# add new Components to the installed VS Pro 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed VS Pro 2022 on my machine successfully. Now I need to add some new components to my VS Pro 2022.

The machine does not have Internet access. But I have the complete installation files on network share.

The following components should be added

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder
Microsoft.ComponentGroup.ClickOnce.Publish
```

connected the to share where the installation files of VS 2022 and run the following command line

.\vs_Professional.exe modify --installpath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\2022" --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder

But it does not work.
How can I add the above components to my installed VS Pro 2022 without have any Internet access?

Regards

Comment: "it does not work." - what happens? Any errors?

Comment: An installed product matching the following parameters cannot be found. installPath:\Xprogram Files\Microsoft Visual studio\2022\Professional.

Comment: As I wrote, I dont have any internet access, it should be installed without connecting to internet